# tSQL - Conversion from varchar to numeric works for all but integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, number-formatting

I have a table with numbers in a `varchar(255)` field. They're all greater than one and have multiple decimal places. I'd like to convert them to integers. According to every web site I've consulted, including  [this one on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728833/convert-a-string-to-int-using-sql-query), either of these should work:

```
SELECT CAST(VarcharCol AS INT) FROM MyTable

SELECT CONVERT(INT, VarcharCol) FROM MyTable
```

These both work for me for every kind of numeric value but `integer` - I can convert to `float`, `decimal`, etc. just fine, but trying to convert to `integer` gives me the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '7082.7758172'
> to data type int.

I've worked around the problem by converting to data type `Decimal(6,0)`, which works fine. But just for my education, can anyone tell me why converting to data type `int` (or `integer`) gives me an error? Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Converting a `varchar` value into an `int` fails when the value includes a decimal point to prevent loss of data.

If you convert to a `decimal` or `float` value first, then convert to `int`, the conversion works.

Either example below will return 7082:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(decimal(12,7), '7082.7758172'));
SELECT CAST(CAST('7082.7758172' as float) as int);
```

Be aware that converting to a `float` value may result, in rare circumstances, in a loss of precision.  I would tend towards using a `decimal` value, however you'll need to specify precision and scale values that make sense for the `varchar` data you're converting.

Answer (score 1):

Actually whether there are digits or not is irrelevant. The . (dot) is forbidden if you want to cast to int. Dot can't - logically - be part of Integer definition, so even:

```
select cast ('7.0' as int)
select cast ('7.' as int)
```

will fail but both are fine for floats.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
declare @v varchar(20)
set @v = 'Number'
select case when isnumeric(@v) = 1 then @v
else @v end
```

and

```
declare @v varchar(20)
set @v = '7082.7758172'
select case when isnumeric(@v) = 1 then @v
else convert(numeric(18,0),@v) end
```

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, you want to convert values *before* the decimal place to an integer.  If so, use `case` and check for the right format:

```
SELECT (case when varcharcol not like '%.%' then cast(varcharcol as int)
             else cast(left(varcharcol, chardindex('.', varcharcol) - 1) as int)
        end) IntVal
FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT cast(column_name as type) as col_identifier FROM tableName WHERE 1=1
```

Before comparing, the `cast` function will convert `varchar` type value to `integer` type.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT
  convert(numeric(18,5),Col1), Col2
     FROM DBname.dbo.TableName
         WHERE isnumeric(isnull(Col1,1)) <> 0
```

Comment: You also might receive this error if your size it too small - ie. originally it was (13,3) but getting error - then I enlarged it and now runs perfectly.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Also, isnumeric doesn't catch everything.