# SQL Case Statement numeric and varcha

Tags: sql, sql-server

[SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWxCU.png)

I want to assign primary to classyear below 9 and sec 9 and above with Preschool as same

Comment: please specify your question clearly

Comment: ALWAYS assign a length to strings in SQL (e.g. `VARCHAR(20)`, not `VARCHAR`) - otherwise, SQL will truncate your string to a single character. Anyway, your issue can be solved with something like `CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Class_Year) = 1 THEN CASE WHEN Class_Year < 9 THEN 'Primary' ELSE 'Secondary' END ELSE Class_Year END AS SchType`

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please include a table of sample data as text within the question.  Please format it as a code segment (highlight the code and click on the `{}` button above the text entry area, or indent each line by four spaces).  Please reproduce your code as text within the question, formatted as a code segment.  Please include another table showing how the output should appear.

Comment: If you define a variable as `varchar` it will be the same as `varchar(1)` -- so in your code value of `@sec` is actually just `S`

Comment: Question is vague. Could you re-write the question?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT Student_Subject_Type_Desc,
       Class_Year,
       CASE
           WHEN Class_Year = 'PreSchool' THEN
               'PreSec'
           WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr1' THEN
               'Voc_Yr1'
           WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr2' THEN
               'Voc_Yr2'
           WHEN ISNUMERIC( Class_Year ) <> 1 THEN
               NULL
           WHEN CAST( Class_Year AS INT ) < 9 then
               'Primary'
           ELSE
               'Secondary'
       END AS SchType
FROM FILNA.dbo.VIEW_FILNA_STUDENTS_SUBJECT
ORDER BY Student_Subject_Type_Desc
LIMIT 1000
```

The `CASE` statement is based upon `Class_Year`, which consists of a string value.  This value will be the equivalent of a number, one of a few acceptable strings (namely `PreSchool`, `Voc Yr1` and `Voc Yr2`), or invalid in some way.

I have started by testing to see if `Class_Year` is equal to one of the acceptable strings.  With these possibilities eliminated, testing to see if the value of `Class_Year` represents a number becomes easier.  I use `ISNUMERIC( Class_Year ) <> 1` to test if `Class_Year` does *not* represent a number and to return the value `NULL` in that case.  If the value of `Class_Year` *does* represent a number then either `Primary` or `Secondary` is returned based on the value of that number, which I obtain from casting the value of `Class_Year` into an `INT`.

Please note that it is not clear from your Question how `Class_Year` values of `0`, negative numbers, too large numbers and noninteger equivalent real numbers should be handled, so I have assumed that they shall not occur or do not need to be tested for.  If they do need to be tested for, then please modify your question to say so.  Also, if you wish for me to test for too large numbers, then please state what the maximum valid number is.

*Appendix*

As for the second stetement from your second Comment, the code you gave was...

```
SELECT Student_Subject_Type_Desc,
       Class_Year,
       CASE
           WHEN Class_Year = 'PreSchool' THEN
               'PreSec'
           WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr1' THEN
               'Voc_Yr1'
           WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr2' THEN
               'Voc_Yr2'
           WHEN ISNUMERIC( Class_Year ) <> 1 THEN
               NULL
           WHEN CAST( Class_Year AS INT ) < 9 then
               'Primary'
           ELSE
               'Secondary'
       END AS SchType
FROM [FILNA].[dbo].[Student_Subject_Desc]
WHERE SchType = 'Primary'
ORDER BY Student_Subject_Type_Desc
```

Because `SchType` is a field that we create using our `CASE` statement from the fields allowed *after* the application of the `WHERE` clause, our `WHERE` clause will not be able to refer to it.  One way to get around this is to use my statement from the beginning of my answer as a subquery to a `SELECT` statement that will return all of its fields subject to your `WHERE` clause.  For example...

```
SELECT Student_Subject_Type_Desc,
       Class_Year,
       SchType
FROM ( SELECT Student_Subject_Type_Desc,
              Class_Year,
              CASE
                  WHEN Class_Year = 'PreSchool' THEN
                      'PreSec'
                  WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr1' THEN
                      'Voc_Yr1'
                  WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr2' THEN
                      'Voc_Yr2'
                  WHEN ISNUMERIC( Class_Year ) <> 1 THEN
                      NULL
                  WHEN CAST( Class_Year AS INT ) < 9 then
                      'Primary'
                  ELSE
                      'Secondary'
              END AS SchType
       FROM FILNA.dbo.VIEW_FILNA_STUDENTS_SUBJECT
     ) AS SchTypeFinder
WHERE SchType = `Primary`
ORDER BY Student_Subject_Type_Desc
LIMIT 1000
```

However, this is less efficient than altering the statement to this form...

```
SELECT Student_Subject_Type_Desc,
       Class_Year,
       'Primary' AS SchType
FROM [FILNA].[dbo].[Student_Subject_Desc]
WHERE ISNUMERIC( Class_Year ) = 1
  AND CAST( Class_Year AS INT ) < 9
ORDER BY Student_Subject_Type_Desc
LIMIT 1000
```

This will only `SELECT` records where `Class_Year` represents a number that is less than `9`, i.e. only those that qualify as `SchType = 'Primary'`.  This removes any need for the `CASE` statement and enables us to always return `Primary` for `SchType`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

[Convert a string to int using sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728833/convert-a-string-to-int-using-sql-query) (on converting a string to an `INT`)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql (on the `ISNUMERIC()` function)

Comment: Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Comment: SELECT [Student_Subject_Type_Desc],[Class_Year], 
   (CASE WHEN Class_Year = 'PreSchool' then 'PreSec'
         WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr1' then 'Voc_Yr1'
         WHEN Class_Year = 'Voc Yr2' then 'Voc_Yr2'
         WHEN Class_Year = '1'OR Class_Year = '2'OR Class_Year = '3'
         OR Class_Year = '4'OR Class_Year = '5'OR Class_Year = '6'
         OR Class_Year = '7'OR Class_Year = '8'then 'Primary'
         else 'Secondary' END) as SchType
  FROM [FILNA].[dbo].[Student_Subject_Desc]
    where SchType = 'Primary'
    group by Class_Year, Student_Subject_Type_Desc

Comment: i want to use allias with the where clause but couldnt...please help

Comment: I have altered my Answer to (hopefully) eliminate the error from your first Comment.  I shall now get stuck into your second Comment's problem.

Comment: Also, why do you want to use an alias with the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Explanations added.