# Convert result of CASE Expression to a number in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have the following `select` query. I want to *convert* it from `string` into a `number`. If I wrap a `TO_NUMBER` around the case expression, I get

> expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

**error**.

```
SELECT CASE SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1) 
         WHEN 'Unspecified' THEN ' '
         ELSE SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1) 
       END as Final_Grade,
```

How can I get `Final_Grade` to be `numeric`?

Thank you!

Comment: CAST or CONVERT = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187928(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728833/convert-a-string-to-int-using-sql-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to int using sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728833/convert-a-string-to-int-using-sql-query)

Comment: use TO_NUMBER( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] ) and replace `WHEN 'Unspecified' THEN ' `' with `WHEN 'Unspecified' THEN -1`, or any other number that make sense

Comment: How are your data samples? Do you want to extract digits from a string(GRADE)? Why do you need space characters? Btw, a case..when expression cannot start in such a way like `CASE SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1)` ..

Comment: Seems like GRADE contains non-numeric data. If you can't figure it out please post a reproducible test case including sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `' '` is not a number, so better figure out what to do.  I would suggest `NULL`:

```
SELECT (CASE SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1) 
           WHEN 'Unspecified' THEN NULL
           ELSE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1)) 
        END) as Final_Grade,
```

Actually, I prefer:

```
(CASE WHEN GRADE NOT LIKE 'Unspecified%'
      THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1)) 
 END) as Final_Grade
```

Or perhaps even more safely:

```
(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(GRADE, '^[0-9]+ ')
      THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(GRADE, INSTR(GRADE, ' ') + 1)) 
 END) as Final_Grade
```